# PHP sort and rsort issue with a 1d array

Tags: php, file, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array that I read in from a file and for some reason it doesn't work. It's never sorted.

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 56

    [1] => 98

    [2] => 53

    [3] => 49

    [4] => 7

    [5] => 50

    [6] => 56

    [7] => 63

)
```

After I try to sort it with `sort($array)`, this is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 49

    [1] => 50

    [2] => 53

    [3] => 56

    [4] => 56

    [5] => 63

    [6] => 7

    [7] => 98

)
```

The same happens with `rsort` - number 7 is always misplaced and I just can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Given that your results are in alphabetical order, I'd assume your array contains strings, not numbers...

Comment: I've never thought about that ... yes it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag to `sort`?

```
    $a=array(56,98,53,49,7,50,56,63);
    sort( $a, SORT_NUMERIC );
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($a,true));
```

Should outout in increasing order

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 49
    [2] => 50
    [3] => 53
    [4] => 56
    [5] => 56
    [6] => 63
    [7] => 98
)
```

Comment: Glad it helped. the same `SORT_NUMERIC` flag can be used with `rsort` if the order is to be reversed.